# gt color one column based on color name in another column

Tags: r

I am creating a formatted table using `gt` in R.  My data frame has several columns, a name column and then a color column.  How can I color the name column based on the color named in the color column?

Here is some example data:

```
id <- 1:10
res1 <- sample(1:20, 10)
nm2 <-
  c("red",
    "purple",
    "green",
    "pink",
    "yellow",
    "darkred",
    "cyan",
    "black",
    "white",
    "yellow")
res3 <- sample(1:20, 10)
nm4 <- nm2

# Add NAs
res1[6] <- NA
nm2[6] <- "NA"
res3[4] <- NA
nm4[4] <- "NA"
df <- data.frame(id, res1, nm2, res3, nm4)
```

Here is one of my attempts...

```
df %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill("lightgrey"),
    locations = cells_body(rows = seq(1, nrow(df), by = 2))
  ) %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "res1",
    colors = "nm2"
  )
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this?

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# first create a gt object
gt_table <- df %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill("lightgrey"),
    locations = cells_body(rows = seq(1, nrow(df), by = 2))
  )

# paste a color for NA -> "black"
df$nm2[df$nm2 == "NA"] <- "black"

# recolor 
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         color = nm2) %>%
  pwalk(function(row, color, ...) {
    gt_table <<- gt_table %>%
      tab_style(
        style = cell_text(color = color),
        locations = cells_body(rows = row, columns = "res1")
      )
  })

gt_table
```

[image]

OR replace `style = cell_text(color = color),`by `style = cell_fill(color = color),`

[image]